# Как реализовать авторизацию по ролям?

Tags: php, mysql

Имеется страница авторизации и база данных с таблицей пользователей и таблицей ролей этих пользователей. Таблицы связаны внешним ключом. И есть страницы под каждую роль. К примеру для админа, исполнителя и заявителя. Как сделать так, чтобы при авторизации открывалась нужная страница? Например, при авторизации админа открывалась страница для админа и т.д. 
Понимаю что при авторизации нужно записывать в сессию в данном случае три переменных - это логин, пароль и роль юзера. Сравнивать введенные логин/пароль с теми что в базе и смотреть какая у этой связки роль и открывать нужную страницу.
Но пока что не понимаю как это грамотно реализовать, т.к. еще плохо понимаю работу с сессиями, что и как куда передавать. Гугл в этом плане особо не помогает. Хотелось бы простого объяснения как это реализовать с самого начала, с создания сессии.

Comment: Авторизация в MySQL (если имеется в виду авторизация уровня приложения - то зачем вообще тег [mysql]?) выполняется по имени пользователя. Роли - это просто именованные наборы прав.

Comment: *Как сделать так, чтобы **при авторизации** открывалась нужная страница?* Никак. В момент вывода страницы авторизации собственно авторизация не выполнена, и нет способа угадать, каким логином будет авторизовываться пользователь. Вот после авторизации - другое дело...

Comment: @Akina я понимаю что нужно сначала сравнить введенный логин/пароль с теми что есть в базе, а потом уже получить роль указанную для это связки, но как это все в виде кода реализовать?

Comment: В виде кода где? в MySQL? в PHP? в JScript? в HTML? где-то ещё? Вы не валите всё подряд в кучу.

Comment: @Akina в PHP, авторизация на php

Comment: распишите по пунктам что вы делаете и на каком пункте у вас не выходит или не знаете что делать дальше. добавьте какой-то код или псевдокод